# Pass object from local shiny app to (hosting) local R Session?

Tags: r, session, local, shiny

Is there a way to send a parameter (interactively set during a shiny session) to the R session that started the shiny session? E.g.

```
# fire up app locally
myRunApp()
# do something in shiny that defines parameter xy
# access xy in R do something with it?
plot(xy)
```

I know I could save it so file etc. but I was looking for a more direct solution, as I understand the R session itself is "paused" until shiny is stopped.